# Interpolating between models in ROC space

Tags: roc, interpolation, predictor

Suppose I have two models $A$ an $B$ that predict class labels. If these give binary predictions, these will appear as pairs of (false positive rate, true positive rate) in the [ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) space. We should be able to construct different models to achieve any tpr and fpr along the linear interpolation of these curves by assigning the mis-matched points to class 1 or 0 according to some probability (as illustrated in the hand drawn figure below).

[image]

Let us say that model $A$ achieves a true positive rate of $t_A$ at a false positive rate of $f_A$, and $B$ similarly achieves $t_B$ at $f_B$. Now I am trying to stay at the convex hull of the two models, and predict for a false positive rate of $f$. I use the following formula:

1. If $f \leq f_A$, predict $f/f_A$ of the samples predicted by $A$ as $1$, and the rest as $0$.
2. If $f_A \lt f \leq f_B$, predict $1$ for all those predicted by $A$, and also $1$ for $(f-f_A)/(f_B-f_A)$ of those predicted by $B$ but not $A$.
3. If $f_B \le f$, predict $1$ for all those predicted by $A$ or $B$, and also $1$ for $(f-f_B)/(1-f_B)$ of the rest.

This is what I get using this.

[image]

It seems though that something is wrong in this formula. As we can see, I am consistently predicting below the lines connecting $A$ and $B$. This is not due to randomness since I am doing an almost perfect job between the origin and $A$, and also I have used a lot of samples to generate this graph. For one, in the range $f>f_B$, we are actually interpolating between $B$ and $(1,1)$ so we should disregard $A$. I have only written it this way to keep continuity between region 2 and 3. It should actually be predict $1$ for those predicted by $b$ and $(f-f_B)/(1-f_B)$ fraction of the rest. My main question is, what is the correct formula for interpolating between $A$ and $B$?

This is my code for generating this graph in R:

```
n <- 1e6

labels <- c(rep(0,n/2),rep(1,n/2))
fA <- .2; tA <- .6; fB <- .7; tB <- .95
A <- rep(0,n)
A[sample(n/2,fA*n/2)] = 1; A[(n/2)+sample(n/2,tA*n/2)]=1
B <- rep(0,n)
B[sample(n/2,fB*n/2)] = 1; B[(n/2)+sample(n/2,tB*n/2)]=1

Ainds = Filter(function(x) {A[[x]]}, 1:n)
Binds = Filter(function(x) {B[[x]]}, 1:n)
BnotA = Filter(function(x) {B[[x]]&(! A[[x]])}, 1:n)
AorB = Filter(function(x) {A[[x]]|B[[x]]}, 1:n)
notAnotB = Filter(function(x) {! (A[[x]]|B[[x]])}, 1:n)

library(ROCR)

pred.a <- prediction(A,labels)
pred.b <- prediction(B,labels)

pdf("ROC_Interpolated.pdf")

# plot a and b
plot(performance(pred.a,"tpr","fpr"),col="blue",lty=0,type='o',pch=2)
plot(performance(pred.b,"tpr","fpr"),col="blue",lty=0,type='o',pch=2,add=T)



i <- 0
C = list()
pred.c = list()
p = list()
f = list()
for (fgoal in ((1:29)/30)) {
    i <- i+1
    f[[i]] = fgoal
    C[[i]] <- rep(0,n)
    if (fgoal<=fA) {
        p[[i]] = fgoal/fA
        C[[i]][sample(Ainds, p[[i]]*length(Ainds))] = 1
        # C[[i]] <- sapply(1:(2*n),function(x) {if (A[[x]]) rbinom(1,1,p[[i]]) else 0})
    } else if (fgoal<=fB) {
        p[[i]] = (fgoal-fA)/(fB-fA)
        C[[i]][Ainds] = 1
        C[[i]][sample(BnotA,p[[i]]*length(BnotA))] = 1
        # C[[i]] <- sapply(1:(2*n),function(x) {if (A[[x]]) 1 else if (B[[x]]) rbinom(1,1,p[[i]]) else 0})
    } else {
        p[[i]] = (fgoal-fB)/(1-fB)
        C[[i]][AorB] = 1
        C[[i]][sample(notAnotB,p[[i]] * length(notAnotB))] = 1
        # C[[i]] <- sapply(1:(2*n),function(x) {if (A[[x]]|B[[x]]) 1 else rbinom(1,1,p[[i]]) })
    }
    pred.c[[i]] = prediction(C[[i]],labels)
    plot(performance(pred.c[[i]],"tpr","fpr"),col="red",lty=0,type='o',pch=5,add=T)
}


lines(c(0,fA,fB,1),c(0,tA,tB,1),lty=2,col="black")
legend(.4,0.4,legend=c("A","B","interpolated by sampling","theoretical"),lty=c(0,0,0,2),pch=c(2,2,5,NaN),col=c("blue","blue","red","black"))

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back, it was a very simple mistake. Interpolating between models is as simple as sampling between the outputs of the two models. So for example between $A$ and $B$, for every sample choose the output of $B$ with probability $p_B = (f-f_A)/(f_B-f_A)$ and the output of $A$ with probability $1-p_B$. Doing this, I get the expected output:

[image]

The (simplified) code for this is:

```
n <- 1e5

labels <- c(rep(0,n/2),rep(1,n/2))
fA <- .2; tA <- .6; fB <- .7; tB <- .95
A <- c(rbinom(n/2,1,fA),rbinom(n/2,1,tA))
B <- c(rbinom(n/2,1,fB),rbinom(n/2,1,tB))

library(ROCR)

pred.a <- prediction(A,labels)
pred.b <- prediction(B,labels)

pdf("ROC_Interpolated.pdf")

# plot a and b
plot(performance(pred.a,"tpr","fpr"),col="blue",lty=0,type='o',pch=2)
plot(performance(pred.b,"tpr","fpr"),col="blue",lty=0,type='o',pch=3,add=T)

i <- 0
C = list()
pred.c = list()
p = list()
f = list()
for (fgoal in ((1:29)/30)) {
    i <- i+1
    f[[i]] = fgoal
    if (fgoal<=fA) {
        p[[i]] = fgoal/fA
        C[[i]] <- sapply(1:n,function(x) {if (runif(1)<=p[[i]]) A[x] else 0})
    } else if (fgoal<=fB) {
        p[[i]] = (fgoal-fA)/(fB-fA)
        C[[i]] <-  sapply(1:n,function(x) {if (runif(1)<=p[[i]]) B[x] else A[x]})
    } else {
        p[[i]] = (fgoal-fB)/(1-fB)
        C[[i]] <-  sapply(1:n,function(x) {if (runif(1)>p[[i]]) 1 else B[x]})
    }
    pred.c[[i]] = prediction(C[[i]],labels)
    plot(performance(pred.c[[i]],"tpr","fpr"),col="red",lty=0,type='o',pch=5,add=T)
}

lines(c(0,fA,fB,1),c(0,tA,tB,1),lty=2,col="black")
legend(.4,0.4,legend=c("A","B","interpolated by sampling","theoretical"),lty=c(0,0,0,2),pch=c(2,3,5,NaN),col=c("blue","blue","red","black"))

dev.off()
```